# Why is memory stacking up when using gifs in Ursina Engine?

Tags: python, memory, gif, ram

I want to load a gif in ursina engine using the Animation class, it works flawlessly but when I want to reassign the Animation to another gif the memory stacks up like if I opened another gif. I tried to delete the instance and then recreate the gif but the memory keeps stacking up, also I tried to force a garbage collection but it doesn't work either.
What can I do?
The code is something like this:

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.animation import Animation
import gc

app = Ursina()
FC={"FC":80}
monitor = Animation("monitor\gifs\monitor-%d.gif" % (FC["FC"]),loop=False)
monitor.enable()


def recreate_monitor():
    global monitor
    monitor = Animation("monitor\gifs\monitor-%d.gif" % (FC["FC"]),loop=False)
    monitor.enabled = True

def refresh_monitor():
    global monitor
    monitor.sequence.start()

def update():
    global monitor
    if not monitor:
        create_monitor()
    else:
        if monitor.sequence.finished:
            if FC["FC"] != 80:
                monitor.remove_node()
                del monitor
                print("DATA RECOLLECTED: ", gc.collect())
                create_monitor()
            else:
                refresh_monitor()

def input(key):
    if key == "space":
        FC["FC"] = 100


app.run()
```